# Should request models infer nullity?

Tags: android, request, annotations

Given a request model e.g.

```
public class Profile {

    @SerializedName("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @SerializedName("full_name")
    public String fullName;
}
```

Is there any value in inferring nullity? For example,

```
public class Profile {

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @Nullable
    @SerializedName("full_name")
    public String fullName;
}
```

The business logic is done outside of my app. Backend will ignore any extra data I include or exclude. I feel that this is unnecessary, however, a co-worker claims that by default annotations uses @NotNull, so specifying @Nullable will help. Is this true? I cannot find documentation about this.

Comment: By default annotations *do not use NotNull* or any other annotation. They are simply annotations that have no impact at Runtime (at least in Java) but will cause the static analysis (LINT) to scream at you if you try to access a reference without checking for NULL first. What your co-worker is incorrectly stating is that, the absence of annotation means that the compiler assumes NonNull. In practice this is how it looks like, but the theory behind is different. If a field IS nullable, annotating it as such can only help IMO, unless you aren't certain for sure which one it is (you should!) :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Great response! Thank you, this is clear now. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your co-worker is incorrect; what appears to be a NotNull, is, in fact, the LINT static analysis tool not hinting at a potential null.

```
void someMethod(String str);
void someMethod(@NotNull String str);
void someMethod(@Nullable String str);
```

For these three signatures, the bytecode is the same (to the best of my knowledge, at least in Java 1.8). The difference is that LINT by default will only warn you if you violate an explicit contract.

Imagine a useless implementation of each method would look like:

```
void someMethod(String str) {
   str.toString();
}

void someMethod(@NotNull String str) {
   str.toString();
}

void someMethod(@Nullable String str) {
   str.toString();
}
```

All LINT would warn me here, is in the annotated version, but only because I'm **explicitly** saying that it can be null and LINT sees i'm not checking.

Where your coworker is mistaken, is in assuming that the 1st version is considered not null. The difference can be spotted when calling:

```
String myStr; 
someMethod(myStr);
```

In the **non-annotated** version (`void someMethod(String str) {`), there is no warning by default in LINT about passing a null.

However in the **explicitly annotated** version (`void someMethod(@NonNull String str) {`), LINT clearly detects that myStr is not initialized (try even calling like `someMethod(null)` and spot the difference).

Anyway, at the end of the day, annotations are just that, hints so the compiler or an annotation's processor can make decisions; it's also used by the Android Studio plug-in and LINT. Ultimately, the decision to use or not to use the annotations, also boils down to personal preference. That being said, with the growth of Kotlin, these annotations become important in the interoperability of both languages.

Lastly, it's worth mention that the Java compiler will not stop you from compiling said unsafe code, regardless of the annotations, so keep that in mind as well. I personally prefer to have them (even tho I think they look clumsy), because they state a clear intention.